# Remove subviews from an UIView perfomantly?

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, performselector

Hi i'm writing a iOS tiled Map component in Monotouch that requires me to remove and add a large number of (markers)UIViews from a parent UiView as part of the Main thread.

I am specifically implementing clustering for the pins. As they become to close together they cluster into nodes displaying the number of pins the node represents. Depending on the zoom level i need to add and remove pins as they move in and out of nodes

Adding the views is fine as this can be done in bulk with

```
 _parentView.AddSubviews (viewsToAdd.ToArray());
```

plus it can be chunked.

but the remove is killing my performance as each individual view has to be removed with a

```
view.RemoveFromSuperview ();
view.Dispose ();
```

Is there any way to speed up the operation?

I looked into putting the views into an NsArray and using performSelector remove from superview but i couldn't find the correct syntax for that in mono touch

thanks Luke

Comment: Would a CALayer fit your needs? Using them lead normally to more lightweight operations.

Comment: Why does the component require adding and removing views? Perhaps you need to optimize your design. Note the table view and collection view.

Comment: CALayer doesn't really fit my needs as thats more suitable for content that doesn't change. I should say this is a larger tiled mapping component and the UiViews i'm trying to remove and add are pins that cluster into nodes as they get to close together depending on the zoom level. I'll update the question

Comment: You need to use Instruments to see what part of the code is taking much of the performance.

Comment: Hm, what about adding all the subviews into a common superview and then remove the superview to remove them all? But still, not sure if that is the problem. You should profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider recycling your views instead of disposing them and creating new ones. This is something Apple's `MKMapView` provides, but you don't mention if you are using it or not. It works by adding a number of `MKPlacemark` objects, that are represented by `MKAnnotationView` recyclable views as you scroll around the map.

There is a reasonable [example](https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/blob/master/FieldService/FieldService.iOS/Controllers/MainMapController.cs) in Xamarin's Field Service App of using `MKMapView's` `DequeueReusableAnnotation` method. Scroll down to the `MapViewDelegate` nested class.

If you are using another map library, like Google Maps, you should consider keeping a `Queue<T>` of your views in order to recycle them. That way you can merely call `AddSubview` and `RemoveFromSuperview` and not create new objects over and over.